# Prediction of time series with neural network

Tags: regression, time-series, neural-networks, forecasting, residuals

Suppose I get a forecast, from MLP or LSTM - next 7 time steps into the future. I can assess its quality using mean absolute error using cross validation. However, it is not clear, what I should do with residuals.

I met mentioning in a few sources that when fitting a regression model, it is important to investigate **residuals**, so that they are close to normality/have no autocorrelations. Neural networks ARE non-linear regression models. However, while residual analysis is straightforward to do for OLS regression, it is not clear if it is done, or **should be investigated for neural network models?**

Suppose I fit an MLP model on the training set using window of 30 time steps, and forecast (dependent vector) of 7 time steps forward, **do I calculate residual statistics on the training set, or test set? And if so, how is it done for a horizon of 7 days? Does it even make sense since the procedure fitting the values is not OLS? In case they are far from normality, what does it mean in terms of NNs?** (since they overlap, because the window moves by 1 forward, but forecast is 7 days, at any time step, 6 forecasts overlap).

Comment: My understanding is that for any model, if the residual plot shows an obvious trend or shape then the model is insufficient. As a simple example, if modeling a sine wave using a straight line, the residual plot would show some sinusoidal pattern.